# Setting Up Developed Java Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat

I am trying to set up some project in Eclipse which is already developed and has following file structure.

[image: Root Folder Files]

[image: WEB-INF Files]

I know how to setup things in Eclipse and how to run it with Apache Tomcat but when I restart Tomcat it tries to build the web app with tons of errors. The errors are like failed to load libraries (.JAR) and the like. Let me tell you the project is loaded and set in Eclipse perfectly without any single Error. There are many packages in the project as well as JSP files. Why this is not working with Tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you have to set the build path of your project, that is right button click over the project, then build path. That build path must point to your java libraries, or almost every line of the project will be an error.

Comment: I mentioned there are no Error in Eclipse when the project is loaded. What libraries other than JRE, Apache Tomcat, Few third-party are you referring to?

Comment: The source folder where you have placed the java libraries.

Comment: it has to be, normally, inside the project

Comment: Are you sure? I just got to know it's JBoss project specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Get the original WAR file or if there is none, just zip the whole content in a single file which you rename with `.war` extension. Finally, if you have [Eclipse for Java **EE**](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1) version, you can just do *File > Import > WAR* and select the file. Eclipse will automatically create a new *Dynamic Web Project* based on the WAR. If you have standard Eclipse version for Java (non-EE), then you need to upgrade Eclispe first.

However, if the WAR doesn't contain source code (the `.java` files) of the Java classes (the `.class` files) present in `/WEB-INF/classes`, then you'll need to decompile them with some Java decompiler like [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) and then create the package structure with those decompiled classes in the project's source folder yourself.

As to the exceptions/errors you get when running it locally, you just need to fix them *one by one*, starting with the firstmost one. More than often some if not all of the subsequent errors will just disppear. If you fail in understanding the first exception/error, just press `Ask Question` on the right top here.